# while loop problem in python for tiktaktoe

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to programming and even newer to python. As part of my assignment i have to create a tik tak toe game. For the input where the program asks the user to choose a character x or o, i chose to go with a while loop which would also serve as a kind of error handling in case the user mistyped the answer. the loop would go until the user hits x or o. I have tried it in various forms but i just con not make it run as i want it. i am working in Jupiter notebook.

```
def input_player():
    i = input('player1! Please choose your weapon (x or o):  ')
    while i is 'x' or 'o':
        if i != 'x' or 'o':
            print('Please choose the right character X or O')
            input()
            continue
        elif i == 'x' or'o':
            print('Thank You!')
            break
```

the loop keeps asking me the first question even pressing the right characters. Where did i go wrong? 
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: `while i is 'x' or 'o':` is broken

Comment: [Popular error in checking multiple values in condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)